# Need to convert $-mw^2=C(e^{ika}-2+e^{-ika})$ to $w=2\sqrt{\frac{C}{m}}\sin\frac{ka}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to conclude from

$-mw^2=C(e^{ika}-2+e^{-ika})$

that

$w=2\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{m}}\sin\dfrac{ka}{2}.$

Is that possible?

($m, v, k,$ and $ a$ are just some constants -- don't mind them.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ ?

Comment: @MartinR, yeah I'm using the Euler's formulas, but I can't solve it. Is it solvable at all, maybe my tryings are useless?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: 
$$\mathrm e^{ika}+\mathrm e^{-ika}-2=\Bigl(\mathrm e^\tfrac{ika}2-\mathrm e^\tfrac{-ika}2\Bigr)^{\!2}=\Bigl(2i\sin\frac{ka}2\Bigr)^{\!2}.$$

Comment: Is it solvable at all? Can You answer just yes or no?

Comment: You accidentally left the $i$ inside the sine function.

Comment: Oh!  yes. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I got $w=2\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{m}}sin\dfrac{ka}{2}/\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{m}}$

Comment: How did you get the denominator???

Comment: Which one exactly ? The problem is with m, when I divide both sides of equation

Comment: The last one: $\;/\sqrt{\frac1m}$.

Comment: Originally I had this $w=2\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{m}}\sqrt{\dfrac{(sin\dfrac{ka}{2})^2}{m}}$

Comment: It seems you're using the same $m$ twice. To simplify your computation, calculate first $w^2$.

Comment: You mean, take a root before dividing both sides on M? Or divide, but not to split on two fractions, before getting the root?

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!!!!

Comment: No I just mean write $w^2= \dots$, simplify and finally take the root.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help

Comment: Wonderful${ }$!